# Magento2 :Cron script readiness check failed - Found non-writable path (for hidden files)

Tags: magento2, magento-cron, readiness-check

I am new to Magento.
I installed my first project (2.3.3 version). Added some products using the admin panel. Download a free theme from the market place (Templates Master Absolute Theme).

But when I tried to install that
Cron script readiness check failed.
and it shows

> Found non-writable path(s):
>
> /var/www/new-magento.com/.htaccess.sample
>
> /var/www/new-magento.com/.php_cs.dist
>
> /var/www/new-magento.com/.travis.yml.sample
>
> /var/www/new-magento.com/.user.ini
>
> /var/www/new-magento.com/.htaccess

All these files are writable.
Given the 777 permission

```
sudo chmod 777 -R <my root directory>
```

I also tried crone install command.

```
bin/magento cron:install [--force]
```

Please help.